# Catch all StatusCodes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, http-status-codes

Is there an easy way to catch multiple / all http status codes in the web config?
At the moment I have

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Account/Error"/>
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Account/NotFound"/>
</customErrors>
```

but lets say I wanted to catch 501, 502, 503 and etc, is there no way I can do a range or handle all status codes? I would prefer not to hard code every single error if possible

Comment: I don't think you can, at least not in the `customErrors` section of web.config, but why do you want to? Do you anticipate your web app will return all status codes?

Comment: I don't anticipate for my web app to return all status codes, however I just want to catch them in the event that they may happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the defaultRedirect attribute to the customErrors tag.
Search for examples like:
http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/08/error-handling-in-mvc-and-nice-error-pages/

Comment: You're very much welcome, isn't stackoverflow just the best? :)